# Why was there not enough foam in my garlic foam with soy lecithin?

Tags: garlic, molecular-gastronomy, foam

This was my first attempt at making a foam using soy lecithin. I used 3 garlic cloves, 2/3 cup water, 2/3 cup milk. Then i used an immersion blender. I got a bit of foam on top but there wasnt a lot of it. It felt like a waste of a lot of milk. How much foam should I be expecting?

For now, I put the foamy mixture in the fridge, is there a way to salvage and get more foam?

Comment: How much lecithin did you add?

Comment: it was just 2 grams

Comment: What brand / type of soy lecithin did you use? I've had better luck with ones bought specifically from the well known modernist supply places than granules from a health food store. Also, are you keeping the immersion blender half immersed and tilted so it injects a lot of air? In any event, this isn't going to be a real stable foam, it would be one you'd need to make to order probably.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just an idea... I've had problems making foam because of hard/basic tap water (a lot of chalk in the water) - making frape though, not garlic foam:) Foam will more easily form in soft water as you can easily test with a piece of soap. If you have hard tap water you could try using boiled water (some of the chalk in the water will react and leave a residue on the bottom of the pot) or bottled water with pH 7 (neutral). Another idea would be to add just enough acid for neutralisation but I imagine that could be a bit tricky and you'd risk the milk curdling so I wouldn't recommend it.